# User profile Freezes in Android Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, system-freeze, multi-user

I created a new user in my MotoG Android Lollipop and, sometimes while i'm in this new user, my actual aplication freezes by undetermined seconds, and sometimes minimizes the aplication. I only can acess the header menu when it occurs (and I change the user in this case, mainly), even the app list does not work for sometime.

Also it not occurs in the main user. There is a reason for this problem? And I can do something to fix it?

Comment: How much memory do you have? Did you try Wipe cache partition?

Comment: "* I only can acess the header menu*" -- by which, should I assume you mean Status Bar and the Quick Settings Menu?

Comment: 300Mb free RAM, 1Gb free Disk. Yes, It is Status bar and the Quick Settings Menu. Also, if I try to open the Configuration Menu when my Android freezes, it not launch.

Comment: I didn't tried wipe cache partition, also i don't know how it works. Can I lose some important data trying it?

Comment: I wiped my cache partition but the problem stills